# Oracle 12c: Bug with trunc(date) results in wrong data

Tags: oracle12c

I have a very strange behavior on my Oracle 12 c database. When i do something like:

```
select count(*) from fact_table, date_dim, dim_table where 
date_dim.date >= trunc(sysdate)-1
and fact_table.DATE_ID = date_dim.DATE_ID
and fact_table.DIM_ID = dim_table.DIM_ID;
```

...I get a certain number. The strange behavior starts when I change the '>=' to '='- only *then* do I get the *double amount*. I checked the join condition, but as far as I know the amount should be the greater or the same if I filter on date '>=' yesterday instead of date '=' yesterday.

Why does this happen? Is there a setting that could lead to duplicate data in the SQL?

*edited* the join conditions both join conditions have just 1 result.

Comment: If "join cond 1"  or "join cond 2" is `where date_dim.date = trunc(sysdate)-1` or something like that, this behavior would make sense, no?

Comment: I don't think the validity of your results can be evaluated without knowing what the 'join' conditions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some intense analytics i found out that i faced an oracle bug ->  Bug 18461054 : TRUNC WITH DATE BIND ON PARTITIONED TABLE GIVE WRONG RESULTS

So this problem can occure with trunc or round date.

The workaround for current sessions is

```
alter session set "_optimizer_generate_transitive_pred"=false;
```

There is also a patch Patch 18461054: TRUNC WITH DATE BIND ON PARTITIONED TABLE GIVE WRONG RESULTS

Hope that helps someone else than me :)

Best,

Patrick